# Using INSTR and SUBSTR together

Tags: oracle, substring

See the below data below first, i need to calculate the columns HUB_NM, PRODUCT_NM and STRIP_NM from the first 2 columns as described.

```
DEAL_ORIGINATION EXCH_SYMBOL                                    HUB_NM     PRODUCT_NM            STRIP_NM
---------------- ---------------------------------------------- ---------- --------------------- ------------
TT_ICE           IPE e-Gas Oil DEC 2010                                    IPE e-Gas Oil         DEC 2010
GLOBEX           HO DEC 2010                                               HO                    DEC 2010
ICE NG           Firm Phys, ID, GDD - Transco-45 - Next Day Gas Transco-45 NG Firm Phys, ID, GDD Next Day Gas
STUSCO_ICE       Brent Crude Futures - North Sea - Dec12                   Brent Crude Futures   DEC12
```

I can't work out how to do it.  I know I should use SUBSTR and INSTR but I can't figure it out.

A) How to get HUB_NM column value from EXCH_SYMBOL?

```
If T.DEAL_ORIGINATION =  'ICE'
then
    Find 1st space dash space 
    Find 2nd space dash space
    Display the word in between, no space at the end 
elsif T.DEAL_ORIGINATION in ('GLOBEX', 'TT_ICE', 'STUSCO_ICE')
then 
    null;
end if;
```

B) How to get PRODUCT_NM column value from EXCH_SYMBOL?

```
If T.DEAL_ORIGINATION in ( 'ICE',  'STUSCO_ICE')
then
    Display from 1st character to the 1st dash, no space at the end 
elsif T.DEAL_ORIGINATION in ('GLOBEX', 'TT_ICE',)
then 
    Remove -9 caharacters from the end of the word and display the fornt word, no space at the end 
end if;
```

C) How to get STRIP_NM column value from EXCH_SYMBOL?

```
If T.DEAL_ORIGINATION in ( 'ICE',  'STUSCO_ICE')
then
    Find the 2nd space dash space
    Display from then on to the end of the word, no space at the end 
elsif T.DEAL_ORIGINATION in ('GLOBEX', 'TT_ICE',)
then 
    Display the last -8 caharacters from the end of the word, no space at the end 
end if;
```

Comment: could you provide a sample table with inserts for the table or a CTE?  I cannot make head's or tail's out of the sample data.

Comment: one more request, could you put in examples in A,B,C of your intended outout?  and what version of Oracle are you using (are you adverse to a regular expression answer?  REGEXP_SUBSTR & regexp_replace may be the answer you seek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start adding some instructions to create a sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE mytab
( 
DEAL_ORIGINATION VARCHAR2(100),
EXCH_SYMBOL VARCHAR2(100),
HUB_NM VARCHAR2(100),
PRODUCT_NM VARCHAR2(100),
STRIP_NM VARCHAR2(100)
);

INSERT INTO mytab (DEAL_ORIGINATION, EXCH_SYMBOL, HUB_NM, PRODUCT_NM, STRIP_NM) 
VALUES ('TT_ICE', 'IPE e-Gas Oil DEC 2010', null, 'IPE e-Gas Oil', 'DEC 2010' );

INSERT INTO mytab (DEAL_ORIGINATION, EXCH_SYMBOL, HUB_NM, PRODUCT_NM, STRIP_NM) 
VALUES ('GLOBEX', 'HO DEC 2010',null, 'HO', 'DEC 2010' );

INSERT INTO mytab (DEAL_ORIGINATION, EXCH_SYMBOL, HUB_NM, PRODUCT_NM, STRIP_NM) 
VALUES ('ICE NG','Firm Phys, ID, GDD - Transco-45 - NEXT DAY Gas', 'Transco-45', 'NG Firm Phys, ID, GDD', 'NEXT DAY Gas');
INSERT INTO mytab (DEAL_ORIGINATION, EXCH_SYMBOL, HUB_NM, PRODUCT_NM, STRIP_NM)
VALUES ('STUSCO_ICE', 'Brent Crude Futures - North Sea - Dec12', null, 'Brent Crude Futures', 'DEC12');
```

Sure you have to make a lot of work figuring out how the instr and substr results will be. Moreover you will never figure it out by just thinking or writing down tons of parentheses.

My advice is to write a temporary select instruction with partial results, like the following:

```
SELECT deal_origination, exch_symbol,
       INSTR(exch_symbol,' - ')+3 as string_start, 
       INSTR( SUBSTR(EXCH_SYMBOL,INSTR(exch_symbol,' - ')+3) , ' - ')-1 string_length ,
       SUBSTR(exch_symbol, INSTR(exch_symbol,' - ')+3, INSTR( SUBSTR(EXCH_SYMBOL,INSTR(exch_symbol,' - ')+3) , ' - ')-1 ) as RESULT
FROM mytab
```

Please note that the RESULT column is made using the same expressions as string_start and string_length columns.

This also answers to the **A** question

This will give you the initial results, so you will be able to figure out what will happen inside the expression. Then put everything into a DECODE instruction

Example 2:

```
decode ( DEAL_ORIGINATION, 
    'ICE', 'results in case of ICE',
    'GLOBEX', 'results in case of GLOBEX',
    null)
-- the last null is the default condition
```

Finally to remove 9 characters to the end of a work use the LENGTH function

Example 3:

```
-- this removes the last 6 characters from the hello world string
select substr ( 'hello world', 1, length('hello world) - 6 )
```

Accept apologies for being unable to test the Oracle code on an actual machine.